# How to add money in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, currency, money-rails

Lets say I have two string:
"$7.99"
and
"$16.99"

Now, I'm trying to add these values together to get "$24.98".
The money could be in a different currency than USD, but the two strings will always be the same currency.

I'm trying to use a combination of the monetize gem (https://github.com/RubyMoney/monetize)
and the currency gem (https://github.com/hexorx/currencies)

The currency gem contains all the currency information.

Here is my code:

```
require 'monetize'        
require 'currencies'
Money.default_bank = ISO4217::Currency::ExchangeBank.new # from the currencies gem doc
m1 = Monetize.parse "$7.99"
m2 = Monetize.parse "$16.99"
m = m1 + m2
puts m
```

I get the error

```
I18n::InvalidLocale: :en is not a valid locale
```

Even though I loaded the currency bank

Comment: `I18n.config.available_locales = :en`

Comment: can I set every locale available in the Currency::ExchangeBank to be available? I have a lot of potential currencies/locales and would not want to explicitly set each one

Comment: [here is the list](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n#available-locales) of all locales, you can allow all of them if you want